# Using survival analysis parameters from multilevel model as a workaround for censored predictor?

Tags: survival, multilevel-analysis, censoring, stan

I am interested in predicting psychopathology development over time using survival parameters from the survival model.
I have data collected using ESM in daily life during which individuals reported whether they had stressful events and reported their stress for the rest of the day. My overall goal is to find out whether the time to recovery from stressful events can predict psychopathology development. Since my predictor is right-censored and interval-censored, I am thinking how to work around this. My analysis plan therefore was as follows:

1. run a multilevel survival model using `brms` (`Stan`) to subtract coefs representing individual survival parameters;
2. use these individual survival parameters as predictors in the model predicting psychopathology over time in the form of : `psychopathology ~ time*survival_coefs`, including all relevant random effects.

My predictor is both right-censored (not everyone recovers in the follow-up time) and interval censored (we know recovery happened somewhere between one timepoint and another within a day, but we are not sure exactly which minute). So I cannot just use the time to recovery in minutes as a predictor.

My question is whether this analysis plan makes sense?

I have also posted this question on the discourse `Stan` platform (see here https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/survival-analysis-with-right-censored-and-interval-censored-data-with-brms/24668), but have not gotten any further as of yet.

Thanks so much in advance!